# joomla .htaccess file rewrite rule explanation required

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I'm trying to understand the following lines in joomla's .htaccess file. Can someone explain this please

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) index.php
#RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

I want to do some custom redirects

for example
if a url is like this example.com/subdirectory1 i want to redirect to some article. tried adding this line in the .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^somepath index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1&Itemid=12
```

but for some reason the article shows the title even though it's not supposed to show. when i access using the long url string the title doesn't appear if i rewrite it appears.

Please help.

-Vivek

Answer (score 2):

The rules in the first post are very inefficient. Two very slow disk reads are performed for every URL request hitting the server, checking to see if the request resolves to a physical file or folder. These checks are performed even when it is obvious that the request is going to be rewritten (extensionless URL) or is not going to be rewritten (images, CSS files, etc).

By changing the order of the conditions, those very slow disk reads can be eliminated for the vast majority of requests. Those changes appear in the .htaccess file distributed with Joomla 1.5.23 and 1.6.2 onwards, and the file will work with older Joomla releases.

Updating an old version of Joomla to a newer package does not automatically update the .htaccess file. The new .htaccess file is distributed as htaccess.txt and therefore requires a manual edit of the filename to set things up.

Answer (score 0):

Those lines are commented out with the # character at the beginning, so they do nothing. If uncommented, they send all requests for files that Apache can't find a real, physical file for to Joomla's `index.php` for further handling.

Not sure you mean about the "title" appearing. What title?

Comment: sorry i commented it . it's supposed to be uncommented. and the title is the article title

Comment: What would the article title have to do with anything in `.htaccess`? Why shouldn't the title display?

Comment: it's my requirement that the article title should not be displayed. see this rule

RewriteRule ^softwares index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=103&Itemid=103

if someone accesses my site site.com/softwares it should be 
redirected to 
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=103&Itemid=103


when it does the redirection, the article title appears in other words if i access my site like this site.com/softwares title appears whereas if i access my site like this index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=103&Itemid=103 the title disappears

Comment: A RewriteRule will not change the HTML of the page. All it does is create, essentially, a URL alias for an existing path. If the page's title is disappearing/appearing on the page, something else odd is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The Page Title in Joomla should be controlled under the menu item. If you edit that menu item,  there's a "System" tab on the right-hand side, and under there you can set the page title.

Mind, it'll change the minute you link off to a different article/image/video in that component. To get a good hold of page titles on your site, you might want to go to the Joomla Extension Directory and look for some of the plugins there which give you greater control over the page title.